# Multiple instances of shaders

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I recently read that you can

> "have multiple instances of OpenGL shaders"

but no other details were given on this.

I'd like some clarification as to what exactly this means.

For one, I know you can have more than one glProgram running, and that you can switch between them. Is that all this is referring to? I assuming that switching between several created shader programs per frame would essentially mean I am using several programs "simultaneously".

Or does it somehow refer to having multiple "instances" of the *same* shader program? That would make no sense to me.

Some basic clarification would be enjoyed here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a program object you're linking together several shaders. Usually at least a vertex and a fragment shader. Now say you want to render, say some glow around some object. That glow would be created by a different fragment shader, but the vertex shader would be the same as for the regular appearance. Now to save resources you can use the same vertex shader in multiple programs but with different fragment shaders being linked in. Of course you could also have the same fragment shader and different vertex shaders.

In short you can link a single shader into an arbitrary number of programs. As long as the linked shader stages are compatible with each other this helps with modularization.

Comment: HeHe ,+1 , I was too late ;)

Comment: Is it "normal" to switch between shader programs multiple times during a single frame pass, such that you have your glowing object (in your example) rendered with one program, while other objects are rendered with others; essentially, you'd be changing the program and making separate draw calls, all within the same frame. I assume this is common?

Comment: It impacts the performance.You should minimize programs switch as much as possible.Usually it is done in graphics engines via material sorting.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns That is in the end the only way to render objects with different shaders, so yes this is normal. But *Michael* is right in that you usually try to reduce program switches (and other switches, like texture binding) using some kind of render state based sorting. Another option is a single shader program which can operate in multiple modes, based on the values of uniforms (which you would still try to not change for each and every object). But this won't work if the particular modes are too different and comes with it's own cost of increased runtime of the shader program itself.